# multer is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

Hello guys i need your help i cant fixed my problem with multer, file is not being uploaded and req.file is always undefined.
Here is my codes

**addProps.js**

```
const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'public/imahe/' })

router.post('/add', isAuthenticated, upload.single('imahe'), (req, res, next) => {
      console.log(req.body)
      console.log(req.files)
      const member = req.user
      Members.findOne({})
      const props = new Property({
        pname: req.body.pname,
        ptype: req.body.ptype,
        price: req.body.price,
        pterm: req.body.pterm,
        location: req.body.location,
        description: req.body.description,
        gallery: req.body.imahe,
        owner: member._id
      })
      props.save( (err, props) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Unable to register your data: ' + err)
          throw err
        }
        console.log('Property Added Successful!')
        res.redirect('/dashboard')
      })
    })
```

**addproperty.ejs**

```
<% include header%>

  <div class="row">
    <form class="col s12" method="POST" action="/property/add">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="file-field input-field">
          <div class="btn">
            <span>File</span>
            <input type="file" name="imahe">
          </div>
          <div class="file-path-wrapper">
            <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" value="submit">Submit
        <!-- <i class="material-icons right">send</i> -->
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>


  <% include foot%>
```

req.file or req.files is always returning undefined in my side, i dont have any other error, i try to find some solution

btw here is my header

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization')

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Controll-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET')
        return res.status(200).json({})
    }
    next()
})
```

Comment: You code here says `req.files` and not `req.file`

Comment: i already tried both sir

Comment: What does `req.file` output on the console ?

Comment: its 'undefined' sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the **enctype** as **multipart/form-data** of form.

> When you are writing client-side code, all you need to know is use multipart/form-data when your form includes any  elements.

Hope following code snippet would be helpful.

```
<form class="col s12" enctype='multipart/form-data' method="POST" action="/property/add" >
```

For more detail, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) answer.

Comment: req.file still undefined sir and file still now uploaded, i tried what you said. btw i edited the question and i added the res.header.. someone told me that it can affect also

Comment: Have you tried not set **dest** for multer, just use **var upload = multer()**

Comment: Have you restart your node server? Because I've tested your example on my local. It work perfectly.

Comment: i already restart it sir, still no luck :( is that conflic with body-parser ?

Comment: It won't be, https://ufile.io/hjh61, this is fork of you code on my end. You could play around and see if there are any other difference.